# location.window.assign appending numbers to URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure I'm overlooking something here but, I have code like so (its more complicated but I think I can safely break it down to these components):

`setTimeout(window.location.assign(page),400);`

page is a url like `'http://www.this.com'`

The problem is that the newly assigned page has RANDOM numbers appended to it. To clarify, instead of being redirected from here.com to here.com/there, it goes here.com to here.com/-54

It looks like I'm returning a value somewhere but I'm not sure where the misuse is as I'm unfamiliar with this function. Anyone see where things have gone awry?

Thanks!

Comment: Examining the code that determines page would reveal where your numbers are coming from.

Comment: As a sidenote. The redirect is actually done right away instead of after 400ms. This is because the code is executed immediately. Either put quotes around it, or preferably wrap it inside a function(){}. End result should be: setTimeout(function(){window.location.assign(page)}, 400);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this out in Firefox and I'm not getting any problems (well, other than what @Gerben mentioned in comments)

```
setTimeout(window.location.assign("http://google.com"),400);
```

So, I have some questions for you:

- What browser are you using?
- Have you tried this and experienced the same problem in other
  browsers?
- Have you tried checking the string in the page variable? alert(page);

FYI @Gerben means to rewrite your code like this if you want the timeout to actually work

```
setTimeout(function() {window.location.assign(page);},400);
```